# SwingWorker and retrieving data from socket

Tags: java, sockets, swingworker

I have code like this

```
try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(888);
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine, outputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            outputLine = "SRV:>"+inputLine+"<:VRS";
            out.println(outputLine);
            taWyjscie.append(outputLine+"\n");
            if (inputLine.equals("Bye."))
                break;
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close(); 

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        taWyjscie.append("Błąd I/O: "+ex.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n");
    }
```

It works, but app is unusable until client sends "Bye.".

I want to be able to send messages to client from server by gui, so im fighting with SwingWorker, i got this:

```
try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(888);
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine, outputLine;

        zadanie = new ServerTask(in);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        taWyjscie.append("Błąd I/O: "+ex.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n");
    }

 private class ServerTask extends SwingWorker<String, String> {
    private BufferedReader iin;

    public ServerTask(BufferedReader win) {
        this.iin = win;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        String input;
        while ((input = iin.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(input);
            publish(input);
            if (isCancelled())
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for(String el : chunks) {
            textAreaOUT.append(el+"\n");
        }
    }

}
```

now i cant send message from server to client, but messages from client are not displayed in textArea. Im fighting with since morning and i cant get idea how swingworker is working...

PS. this try ... catch in front is in button actionperformed function (if it makes any differece)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `execute` on your `SwingWorker`, thats your first bug.  Start there..